# returning a data type from a fn literal

Tags: clojure

The below expression works -

```
((fn[n][(take n (range))]) 10)
```

While the below throws an error -

```
(#([(take % (range))]) 10)
```

Why cant I just return a data type from a function literal ?

Comment: I don't have access to a computer, but macroexpand the fn literal and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutely want to return "data" from an anonymous function using the `#` reader macro just use `do`.

```
#(do [1 2])
```

As @Mars said you also have the alternative to use the `vector` function.

```
#(vector 1 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `#` anonymous function macro expands into a `fn` form e.g.

```
#([1 2])
```

is expanded into `(fn* [] ([1 2]))`

as you can see, when this is called, the vector you are trying to return will be called as a function, which will fail as no arguments are provided. This is the same issue you have:

```
#([(take % (range))])
```

is expanded into

```
(fn* [x] ([(take x (range))]))
```

Comment: so how do I write a function literal where I just want to return a vector ?

Comment: @murtaza52 - Do you want to convert the sequence returned from `take` into a vector? You can use `#(vec (take % (range)))`. If you want to return a vector containing the sequence I think you'll need to use the `fn` form.

Comment: Use `vector` instead of `[...]` as the outer expression in a `#()` function.